# What do I put in for Uri (I am using an EventSource for android a git)?

Tags: android, eventsource

What do I put in for Uri? I am using an EventSource for android [a git](https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android)

```
private void connect() {
    Thread eventThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                eventSource = new EventSource(Uri, new SSEHandler(), extraHeaderParameters, true);
                eventSource.connect();
            } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.v("Error starting eventsource", "True");
            }
        }
    });
    eventThread.start();

}
```

Comment: How about a server URL? Like "http://localhost:9292/"

Comment: I tried that                     eventSource = new EventSource(("local.host"), new SSEHandler(), extraHeaderParameters, true);

Comment: it did not work, it cannot resolve the constructor

Comment: If you look at the class you can see that it has a constructor, which takes an URL object. So use: URL("http://whatever").

Comment: URL("local.host"), new SSEHandler(), extraHeaderParameters, true

Comment: I tried that it says method call expected then I added new and it says cannot resolve constructor

Comment: new URL("localhost")

Comment: Ya, I tried that and then it says it cannot resolve constructor

Comment: Why don't you check what kind of constructors the EventSource has and just give the right parameters.

Comment: Well then we get back to the question of what a Uri is because I checked the parameters and they are               this(URI.create(uri), sslEngineFactory, eventSourceHandler, exposeComments);

Comment: As Java documentation says: "A URI is a uniform resource identifier while a URL is a uniform resource locator. Hence every URL is a URI, abstractly speaking, but not every URI is a URL". It has the same constructor as URL: URI(String str).

Comment: so the constructor is URI(String "value")?